# vscode google chrome scrolling height

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, localhost

recently I can no longer scroll through vscode with an open website.
it doesn't work in firefox and chrome.
i use xampp and fiveserver. everything up to date

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYocP.png)

Answer (score 0):

i have found the problem:
css

```
body {
overflow:hidden;
}
```

by mistake!